# Is there a way to add an httpModule when webApi is running with the HttpSelfHostServer?

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

I have a MVC4 webapi controller. It has no parameter-less constructors. So, i use Windsor dependency resolver and everything is fine when work under System.Web.Http.WebHost. But, when I try to use HttpSelfHostServer, i get the exception message:

`Looks like you forgot to register the http module Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule
To fix this add
&lt;add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" /&gt;
to the &lt;httpModules&gt; section on your web.config.
If you plan running on IIS in Integrated Pipeline mode, you also need to add the module to the &lt;modules&gt; section under &lt;system.webServer&gt;.
Alternatively make sure you have Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 assembly in your GAC (it is installed by ASP.NET MVC3 or WebMatrix) and Windsor will be able to register the module automatically without having to add anything to the config file.`
Obviously, the windsor di cannot register his HttpModule. I've tried to add

`<system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>`

in my app.config, no luck. Tried the WebActivator to use PreApplicationStart method with no luck as well. Is there any way to add a httpModule for self-hosted webapi app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HttpModules cannot be used when self-hosting. They are ASP.NET specific features.

Comment: Ok, then there is something in the server that can offer per-request lifestyle? Cannot believe that i need to rewrite all DI code just because i changed hosting type?

Comment: @brainboost the problem is with your IoC container. For ASP.NET Web API, you cannot rely on anything which is ASP.NET specific but your IoC container seems to be doing exactly that. For example, Autofac has a specific integration package for ASP.NET Web API and they have a specific `PerApiRequestLifetime` thing.